# React router using HashRoute with URL's that don't have a hash

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We have a scenario where users link to our app from an external source and the url has a hash that does not play nice.

Example of the problematic URL : `https://somewebsite.net/#/response/`

That URL loads the component at this route: `/`, but we want to load this one: `/response`

In order to fix that we used `HashRouter` like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={['/', '/index.html']}>
        {location.hash.includes('response') ? (
            <HashRouter basename="/response" hashType="slash">
                <Response/>
            </HashRouter>
        ) : (
            <Checkout />
        )}
    </Route>
    <Route path="/order-received">
        <OrderReceived />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/response">
        <Response />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

That makes it so we can load the component, but it becomes a problem when we try to route to another path.

This does not work: `history.push('/order-received');`

Instead of going to `https://somewebsite.net/order-received` is goes to `https://somewebsite.net/#/response.order-received`

I was able to overcome the problem by having this component load first to remove the `/#` form the URL, but this feels really hacky.

```
const RemoveHashFromUrl = () => {
    // removes `/#` from the URL and loads the component at https://somewebsite.net/response/
    const url = window.location.href.replace('/#', '');
    window.location.href = url;

    return null;
};

export default RemoveHashFromUrl;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Note: the `<Switch>` is a child of `<Router>`

Answer (score 1):

After reaching out for help on twitter, I got [this](https://twitter.com/mjackson/status/1270851095821078531?s=20) answer and refactored to this:

```
const RemoveHashFromUrl = () => {
    const url = window.location.href.replace('/#', '');
    window.location.href = url;
};



<Switch>
    <Route exact path={['/', '/index.html']}>
        {location.hash ? removeHashFromUrl() : <Checkout />}
    </Route>
    <Route path="/order-received">
        <OrderReceived />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/response">
        <Response />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Did it helped ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa yes, this solved the issue.  If any URL has a hash in it, this removes it and refreshes the page at the intended route.